# Why are FullSeriesCollection format changes affect two data series at the same time?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have an XY scatter chart with seven data series on it (using Office 365). I am trying to set the format for the data series using VBA, and it all works fine with the exception that the first series is inexplicably linked to the seventh series. The code looks something like this:

```
'Series 0
With Sheet1.ChartObjects("MyChart").Chart.FullSeriesCollection("Type_0")
    With .Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
    End With
    .Format.Glow.Radius = 0
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    .MarkerStyle = 1
End With

'Series 1 to 6
For i = 1 To 6
    With Sheet1.ChartObjects("MyChart").Chart.FullSeriesCollection("Type" & i)
        .MarkerStyle = -4105   'On
        .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        With .Format.Glow
            .Radius = 0
            .Color.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
            .Color.TintAndShade = 0
            .Color.Brightness = 0
            .Transparency = 0
            .Radius = 5
            .Color.RGB = RGB(105, 211, 33)
        End With
        With .Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        End With
    End With
Next i
```

It doesn't matter which order I put those blocks in, or even if I try to adjust the series formatting manually in the Format Shape window, anytime I try to change Series7, the exact same change applies to Series0 and vice versa.

What kind of awful setting have I enabled that makes that happen, and how do I turn it off?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem.  As a result, I'll delete my post.

Comment: @Domenic no worries, I updated my question to make that aspect clearer. Thank you for the feedback.